# Impala jdbc driver work with Pentaho Designer

Tags: pentaho, impala

I have some trouble to get impala jdbc driver working with Pentaho Designer.

I got the jdbc driver from [cloudera website](https://downloads.cloudera.com/impala-jdbc/impala-jdbc-0.5-2.zip). After extracting the drivers and put them under lib/jdbc, I set up connection via Generic Database.

- The custom connection url is: jdbc:hive2://example.com:21050/;auth=noSasl
- The custom driver class name is: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

I tried a simple query like "SELECT count(*) FROM table_1;", and got an error: "ParentException: 
java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Matt from Pentaho submitted pull request to apache repository on github: https://github.com/apache/hive/pull/9

This pull request contains implementation of all needed methods in JDBC driver for Pentaho tools. I fetched his commit, built jar and copied it into libext/JDBC directory instead of jar from Cloudera website. Driver still misses lot of methods, but is able to perform basic operations on Impala.

Answer (score 1):

Pentaho does not support impala in previous versions. If you are using 4.4.2 PDI,you can use it for instaview.

Impala will be officially support in pentaho 5.0 and its already been released.